# What is the purpose of poking in Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook friend who keeps on poking me.  I usually poke back to be polite. However, I don't understand what it's for.

Other than a small notification, what does poking somebody on Facebook do?  What is it for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's main use is just to get attention - a reminder that you know them on Facebook.

Mark Zuckerberg once said during a Facebook webinar:

> When we created the poke, we thought it would be cool to have a feature without any specific purpose. People interpret the poke in many different ways, and we encourage you to come up with your own meanings.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_features#Poke

Answer (score 2):

I use the poke as a way of saying "hi" to someone without having to necessarily get into a conversation... It can also be a way of saying "Hey, been thinking of you" or "What's up?"

It can also be a unique way to have fun on Facebook, like having "poke wars".